# Sort array into sub-arrays based on index in Java

Tags: java, sorting

Basically, I have a 54 element single dimensional array that I wish to split quickly into a two dimensional array containing 20 very specific subarrays of the original array (and ordered correctly).

consider the integers in the I/O as indices of the original array.

input: {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9......53} the array containing 54 elements

output: {{0,9,51}, {1,52}, {2,17, 53}, {3,10}, {5,16}, {6,11,12} ...} the multidimensional array of 
subarrays of the input array

I am currently hardcoding the subarrays but it is tedious and slow. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: I do not see any pattern on the subarrays. What are the rules?

Comment: what is the criteria for splitting the elements? if you have tried some code to implement that criteria, please add it to the question.

Comment: That's the thing, there IS no discernable pattern. The original array represents a rubiks cube, and the sub arrays represent the individual cubies on a cube.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following. I assume you initialize your sub-arrays yourself. But the sorting of the sub-arrays should be simple as following.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Initialize your original array
    int[] original = new int[54];

    // Create a master array containing 20 sub-arrays
    int[][] array = new int[20][];

    // sub array
    array[0] = new int[3]; // and populate the sub-array values
    array[1] = new int[2]; // and populate the sub-array values
    // .
    // .
    // .

    // Iterate over the sub arrays and sort the numbers
    for (int[] subarray : array) {
        Arrays.sort(subarray);
    }
    // At this point you've achieved what you wanted
}
```